# How to perform exception handling (try-catch) inside Django template tag?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

For a django requirement, i need to add exception handling inside the django template using django template tags.

```
try:
    mem = e.memberOf

except LDAPCursorError:
    mem = ""
```

This is the requirement. I need to do this using Django template tag.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of doing this unfortunately. The Django template isn't necessarily an environment for traditional coding. It is more for integrating certain elements of code with your HTML display. Any errors such as debugging and try-catch should be pushed up to the model or view.

Answer (score 0):

in your views

```
from django.template.defaulttags import register
@register.filter
def sometag(e):
  try:
    mem = e.memberOf
  except LDAPCursorError:
    mem = ""
  return mem
```

and in your templates

```
{{someting|sometag}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the chunk of [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) you are looking for:

> Since the template language doesn’t provide exception handling, **any exception raised from a template filter will be exposed as a server error**. Thus, filter functions should avoid raising exceptions if there is a reasonable fallback value to return. In case of input that represents a clear bug in a template, raising an exception may still be better than silent failure which hides the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Django does not allow you to do this outside of the box. However, Django allows you to build custom template tags and template nodes.
You will need the [advanced custom template tags documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#advanced-custom-template-tags).